# How to get multiple images for same id from database in jsp servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

**index.jsp**
This is my jsp code

```
 <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
<title>My JSP 'index.jsp' starting page</title>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
<meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
</head>
       <sql:setDataSource var="webappDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bharatwellness"user="root" password="naveen" />
    <sql:query dataSource="${webappDataSource}" sql="select * from individaulpartner " var="result" />

    <table width="100%" border="1">
     <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
       <tr>
        <td>${row.id}</td>
        <td>${row.fname}</td>
        <td>
           <img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/ImageServlet?id=${row.id}" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/ImageServlet?id=${row.id}" />certificate</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**ImageGetTest.java**
This my servlet code

```
   package com.server.servlet;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.sql.*;
   import javax.servlet.*;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



  public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {

  final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase";
  final String User = "root";
  final String Password = "password";
  try {
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, User, Password);

    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from usertable where  id=?");
   stmt.setLong(1, Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id")));
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
   if (rs.next()) {
    response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("image"));
    response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("certificate1"));
   }
   conn.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

}
```

This is my table from where i am fetching my data
         [image]

**I am able to show only single image or single certificate for one id . How can I show all file on jsp page. Please help me out...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the Sevlet for each individual image. So in your JSP you need to do somthing like:

```
<td>
   <img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/ImageServlet?id=${row.id}&name=image" />
   <img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/ImageServlet?id=${row.id}&name=certificate" />
</td>
```

and in your Servlet check the additional 'name' parameter to determine which image to send back:

```
   if (rs.next()) {
    if(request.getParameter("name").equals("image")
        response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("image"));
    }else{
        response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("certificate1"));
    }
   }
```

The problem with all of this is that it is not dynamic. To make it handle any number of images for a given entity you need to have some knowledge of the available images when the JSP is processed and have a loop which will generate an `<img/>` tag for each image and call the Servlet with the necessary paramaters.

This will also probably involve some database update: images go into a different table with a FK to the corresponding user.

```
img_id  user_id     image_data
1       1           bytes
2       1           bytes
3       1           bytes 
4       1           bytes
```

Now you get a handle on the image ids for the relevant user and load them one-by-one by passing the id to the Servlet.

Comment: But I want both the value

Comment: I want image and certificate both together on jsp page

Comment: You are getting both values!! You call the Servlet twice one for each image required. Otherwise your browser is going to somehow split the stream of bytes you send back from a single request and output 2 images???? Good luck with that!!

Comment: But the way you are telling it is showing the single image. instead of first image it is showing "image" icon and the second image is shown

Comment: I have added two image tags to your page so I am baffled with your comment. It is a minor change to your code. Why don't you give it a try??

Comment: thanks..its working fine now....i made mistake...i was using &name=certificate in double quotes

Comment: what can i do if two more images are there????? i mean for four images in a row of database...(as you can see in mysql table)

Comment: See update. You need to make it dynamic to handle any number of images.